# Map same key for different actions in normal vim mode and inside NERDTree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I want to map Alt+F1 to :NERDTreeFocus while in normal vim mod and to :NERDTreeToggle while inside NERDTree view. I've tried this:

```
map <silent> <M-1> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nmap <silent> <M-1> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
```

But it does not work, obviously, I don't understand how bindings work in vim. Can you please help me with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your distinction between `:map` and `:nmap` only concerns the *modes* the mappings apply to; what you need here is a distinction between the *scratch buffer* that NERDTree uses for its user interface and all other buffers. Fortunately, Vim allows to define mappings that apply only to the current buffer: [`:help :map-local`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-local)

In order to set this up, you need to be inside the active NERDTree buffer. Fortunately, the plugin sets a custom *filetype* for its scratch buffer, and so the [`FileType`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#FileType) event can be used to hook into the setup without having to directly modify the plugin or all commands that launch it:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <M-1> :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
:autocmd FileType nerdtree nnoremap <buffer> <silent> <M-1> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

#### Additional comments

- [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.
- `<M-1>` should be triggered by <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>, not by <kbd>F1</kbd> (unless you have a strange keyboard setup)